# Import and register all classes from models in admin-django

Tags: django, django-templates

In myApp, I have multiple classes in models. I would like to import all of these classes in admin.py and register.

Is it possible without repetition such as

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import (classA,classB, classC)
```

1. Could I import all the items without explicitly referring as done above
2. Could I also register all at one time

Thanks

Jeff

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try this :-

```
import inspect
import models 

for name, obj in inspect.getmembers(models):
    if inspect.isclass(obj):
        admin.site.register(obj)
```

This will get all the class of models.py and register on admin under loop.

I have not try it but its work same for getting classes on python.

Comment: NameError: name 'ss' is not defined

Comment: Does this import only the models related to the particular app or does in inherit all the models in all the apps ?

Comment: ss not defined , corrected it.  this take all the  class name written in models.py file  within the app.

Comment: can we also pass the other defined classes in admin.py while registering model?

Comment: @RajuSingh what do you mean by other define classes?

Comment: Now, I don't remember exactly. But, I guess I could have figured that out as I up voted your answer.

Answer (score 0):

you can register all model by using this:

from django.db.models.base import ModelBase
    from django.contrib import admin
    import models

```
for model_name in dir(models):
    model = getattr(models, model_name)
    if isinstance(model, ModelBase):
        admin.site.register(model)
```