# Django admin.site.register throws TypeError for models class

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models

This is a follow-on question to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45232541/import-and-register-all-classes-from-models-in-admin-django) question.

I would like to automate the import of classes from a django `models.py` file and then register each with `admin.site.register()`.  Here is my code:

```
from django.contrib import admin
import inspect
from . import models 

for name, obj in inspect.getmembers(models):
    if inspect.isclass(obj):
        admin.site.register(obj)
```

This code throws a `TypeError: 'type' object is not iterable`.

The OP marked this question as answered and I've found several other examples where this code is presented.  I've also reviewed the documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html) and didn't see anything that would indicate that this is wrong.

## Full Traceback:

```
Bills-MacBook-Pro:Pro billarmstrong$ python manage.py runserver/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py:309:RuntimeWarning: Model 'ProWP.p_item' was already registered. Reloading models is not advised as it can lead to inconsistencies, most notably with related models.  new_class._meta.apps.register_model(new_class._meta.app_label, new_class)/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py:309:RuntimeWarning: Model 'ProWP.p_item' was already registered. Reloading models is not advised as it can lead to inconsistencies, most notably with related models.
  new_class._meta.apps.register_model(new_class._meta.app_label, new_class)
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function check_errors.<locals>.wrapper at 0x108f1dea0>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 225, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 112, in inner_run
    autoreload.raise_last_exception()
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 248, in raise_last_exception
    raise _exception[1]
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 327, in execute
    autoreload.check_errors(django.setup)()
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 225, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 120, in populate
    app_config.ready()
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/apps.py", line 23, in ready
    self.module.autodiscover()
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/__init__.py", line 26, in autodiscover
    autodiscover_modules('admin', register_to=site)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/module_loading.py", line 47, in autodiscover_modules
    import_module('%s.%s' % (app_config.name, module_to_search))
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/Users/billarmstrong/Documents/GitHub/Core/WebDataCollect/Pro/ProWP/admin.py", line 7, in <module>
    admin.site.register(obj)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py", line 102, in register
    for model in model_or_iterable:
TypeError: 'type' object is not iterable
```

After `runserver` a second time there is a new warning - but that wasn't part of the original error.  I included everything for reference.  The `p_item` is a class object in `models.py`

## Final Edit

The warning noted above was a result of a sloppy cut/paste that duplicated a class.  It is irrelevant to the original question or the answer below.

Comment: Here is the reference that throws the error:    `File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py", line 102, in register
    for model in model_or_iterable:
TypeError: 'type' object is not iterable`

Comment: @Evert, thanks - fixed the title.

Comment: Mind if I impress (even if pedantic) the value of a good traceback, and taking note of the actual offending code? Because that made answering and resolving this issue much more obvious than for the initial version of this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At a guess, there are not only `django.db.models.Model` classes imported. Probably, your local `models` module contains a few more items, including other classes (which makes the `if inspect.isclass` pass). You may want to perform an additional `issubclass(obj, django.models.Model)` or similar check.

The fact that it works in the linked question, suggests you have additional code in your local `models.py` module, possibly through from imports (making it hard to notice). But an additional check to see that `obj` is an actual Django model (as mentioned above), is probably safer than trying to remove that extra code.

All in all, try the following (untested):

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.db.models import Model
import inspect
from . import models 

for name, obj in inspect.getmembers(models):
    if inspect.isclass(obj) and issubclass(obj, Model):
        admin.site.register(obj)
```

Comment: This worked...  But I'm confused as to why.  The `models.py` module has four Class objects that all inherit from `models.Model`.  This should cause `inpsect.isclass(obj)` to be TRUE.  There is only one other complexity which must cause the `.isclass` to be True but still throw the type error.  Specifically, I've used several decorators from the Class property (`@property`) which must be true for `.isclass(obj)`, but is not iterable.  I take it from the code above that it is a class, but is not a subclass of Model and therefore not part of the admin structure.  Is that correct?

Comment: Debug: print out your `obj` as you iterate through them. If you remove the `issubclass` test, it should print the offending object just before the crash.

Comment: The offending object is `<class 'django.core.validators.RegexValidator'>`.  Which I now see is in reference to a one of the model class attributes.  I now see that the `.getmembers()` will retrieve all classes in the module regardless of where they are and that the `.issubclass()` will filter out only the Model members.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

by adding models.Model in model solved this issue for me

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).